# What if you update your version of woocommerce,What happned to our data?

Tags: woocommerce

What if you update your version of woocommerce,What happens to our data? Does it remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Your products, orders and customer data is stored in your database, so updating WooCommerce *shouldn't* affect them, but **you should always backup your database before you update anything** just in case something goes wrong. You can either use a plugin like [WP migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/), or else [export a copy of the DB via PHPMyAdmin](https://css-tricks.com/back-wordpress-database/#article-header-id-2).

If your theme uses custom templates for WooCommerce, these may have to be updated: WooCommerce will flag any templates that need updating.

If you've made any changes to the WooCommerce plugin files themselves you will **definitely** lose those changes: you should avoid editing plugin files directly.

Finally, it's worth reviewing the [WooCommerce changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woothemes/woocommerce/master/CHANGELOG.txt) to see what changes have been made and how they may impact you.